# shell-command output in a frame instead of splitting the active window

Tags: shell, emacs

For convenience I am using `shell-command` in Emacs for latex/dvips and other commands. While the default behavior of the `shell-command` output is to split the currently active window, I would rather have it display the output-buffer in a new frame. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There are other, better, ways to run `latex` from `emacs`

Answer (score 1):

For a small LaTeX document, you could consider its latexing as a "[compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html)" command, from the Emacs point of view.

I suggest ending your `foo.tex` document with a comment like

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Local Variables: ;;
%% compile-command: "lualatex --halt-on-error --file-line-error foo"
%% End: ;;
```

Adapt that to your needs. Read about [local variables in files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html).

My `~/.emacs` is partly shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496124/50557). Then I am latexing that document with <kbd>F12</kbd> which is bound to `recompile`, which on my system shows the "compilation" (i.e. the LaTeX-ing) in another frame.

PS. Beware of the terminology: emacs frames are not window manager frames.